# Instagram "Photos of You" API support

Tags: api, instagram

Is there any way how to get list of photos where owner of access_token is tagged? So basically exact result set as you can see on your Instagram app profile -> Photos of You section.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, currently there is no API for getting "photos of you"